# how to write a powershell script for load balancing using NLB

Tags: powershell, teamcity, windows-server-2012, nlb, octopus-deploy

I am doing octopus deployment using team-city on servers that are load balanced. I want to write a powershell script so I can do the load balancing of servers in a powershell predeploy script before octopus deploy a site. Also then want to use post deploy script to put back the server. Any idea how can i write as new to powershell.
using teamcity, octopus, windows server12.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what load balancing technology you are using, so I am going to assume Windows Network Load Balancing (NLB).  There are a collection of cmdlets that can help you control the load balancing state of your server.

The cmdlets are described here: [Network Load Balancing cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817138.aspx)

To use the commandlets you'll need to first import the module.

```
Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters
```

Then you can see all the commands available to you:

```
Get-Command –module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters
```